# ANTLR rewrite rules in grammar file

Tags: parsing, tree, antlr

I have a rule that looks like this:

```
a : (b | c) d;

b : 'B';

c : 'C';

d : 'D';
```

With this grammar ANTLR builds a flat parse tree. How can I rewrite the first rule (and leave the other two unchanged) so that whatever is matched is being returned under a root node called A?

If the first production rule was like this:

```
a : b d;
```

then it could have been rewritten as

```
a : b d -> ^(A b d)
```

and it would have solved my problem. However the first grammar rule yields more than one possibility for the resulting parse tree `^(A b d)` or `^(A c d)`.

How do I express this when rewriting the rule?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Tag removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `?` operator in the rewrite as follows.

```
a : (b | c) d -> ^(A b? c? d);
```